# How to access properties of a color bar through the axes instance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am using a function that uses MatPlotLib to generate a plot and an associated color bar. However, the function only returns the axes instance and not the color bar one.

I would like to change the label of the color bar. Is there a way to access to the color bar properties given only the axes instance?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749741/matplotlib-colorbar-change-ticks-labels-and-locators) may be helpful

Comment: @CDJB, Thanks for the link. However, in that question, the color bar instance is created explicitly as `cbar` and then you can freely access all its attributes. In my case, I only have the axes instance and no access to the color bar

Answer (score 1):

A basic design principle is that function should return the artist that it creates. From that you can get the colorbar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(ax=None):
    ax=ax or plt.gca()
    sc = ax.scatter([1,2,3], [1,3,2])
    ax.figure.colorbar(sc)
    return sc

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = function(ax=ax)

sc.colorbar.set_label("My Label")

plt.show()
```