# Add custom labels to seaborn color palette

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

low = '#00FF00'
medium = '#FFFF00'
high = '#FF0000'

plt.figure(figsize=(1,2))

sns.color_palette("blend:#00FF00,#FFFF00,#FF0000",as_cmap=True)
```

The result that I get is:

[image]

But the labels are "under, bad, over". Not sure from where it is pulling it, is there a way to rename or remove those variables? I tried the following, but did not work

```
ax = sns.color_palette("blend:#00FF00,#FFFF00,#FF0000",as_cmap=True)
ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_label("Hello")
```

I want the labels to be low, med and high

Comment: Welcome to SO! The first code block in the question doesn't reproduce the figure you have shared - it just creates a blank figure. Can you please check the code?

Comment: I rechecked the code and it shows the figure that I shared. Not sure why it is showing blank figure on your end :(

Comment: `color_palette` doesn't return a matplotlib axes. I believe what you're seeing is an HTML output.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you are running this inside a Jupyter notebook. The last command (`sns.color_palette(....)`) outputs a colormap, and Jupyter tries to visualize it.  Jupyter shows the name, a colorbar, the `under` (the color for values below `vmin`), the `bad` (the color for `NaN` or infinite values) and the `over` (the color for values above `vmax`).  You can't change this visualization via matplotlib.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749741/matplotlib-colorbar-change-ticks-labels-and-locators to set labels for a colorbar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am running this on Jupyter notebook. Thank you all for the response...I will check the link that you sent in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using appropriate grid of subplots, we can create the expected figure. However, it involves fine adjustments to the plot size and grid size to really get the expected result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

low = '#00FF00'
medium = '#FFFF00'
high = '#FF0000'

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))

# Plot the wider colorbar
ax = plt.subplot(4, 10, (1, 30))
cmap = sns.color_palette("blend:#00FF00,#FFFF00,#FF0000",as_cmap=True)
cbar = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap), cax = ax, orientation="horizontal", ticks=None)
cbar.set_ticks([])
ax.set_title("blend", loc='left', fontweight='bold')

# Function to create box labels and arrange corresponding text
def labels(position, color, label, label_position):
    """
    The first and second arguments decides the position of the subplot and its fill color, respectively.
    The third argument decides the text to put alongside the subplot.
    """
    ax = plt.subplot(5, 100, position)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    x = [0, 1]
    y = [1, 1]
    ax.fill_between(x, y, color=color)
    ax.text(*label_position, label)

labels((401, 403), low, "low", (1.5, 0.2))
labels((449, 451), medium, "medium", (-3.0, 0.2))
labels((498, 500), high, "high", (-1.5, 0.2))

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

In the code above:

- The colorbar spans first thirty subplots of the grid with size 4 x 10 (created using `plt.subplot(4, 10, (1, 30))`. However, to add labels below the colorbar, we can use a grid that has a lot more Axes in a given row, so we have a 5 x 100 grid for labels, but we only utilise a few Axes of this grid to get label boxes (created using `plt.subplot(5, 100, position)`. I was not exactly sure how many rows would be suitable for the grid of labels, but the number of rows definitely need to be more than 3. Otherwise, the grid of label boxes will cover colorbar and it will not be visible.
- We want to make sure that label boxes don't cover the colorbar, thus we use the 5th row of the grid for the boxes. As there are 100 columns in this grid, the first box spans the grid from the index 401 and ends at 403: I used more than one Axes on the grid otherwise the boxes might have looked very thin. This indexing is motivated directly by the expected output: the `medium` box must cover 50th Axes in the last row of the grid (since it should be in the middle), and the `high` box must be at the end of the row, thus it should span from the index 498 to 500.
- [`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) creates an Axes for label boxes whose `xlim` and `ylim` are both set to (0, 1). This means the squares we see at the bottom of the figure are of size 1 x 1.
- Using [`ax.set_ticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticks.html), we have removed the ticks on x- and y-axis of the Axes giving us squares without any ticks. Same for colorbar as well.
- [`ax.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) adds the `label` at the position `label_position`. I wasn't sure about the y-coordinate of the `label`. But since we have already set the x-lim and y-lim of the Axes to (0, 1), x-coordinate in the `label_position` will be more than one if the `label` needs on the right side of the Axes and less than zero if it needs to be on the left side of the Axes e.g. the `x`s in the `label_position` of the `labels` low and medium are of opposite sign. The position of the text ultimately boils down to the font size and the length of the string the `label` represents, thus it's a matter of fine adjustments, but can be programmatically taken care of.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Curious to know how did you come up with the label position (1.5,0.2) and subplot (401,403) position? Is it by trial and error or is there a way to figure that out?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Will go through it to understand how you arrived at the result. Great work!!